# MPI master/worker scenario communicator split

Tags: c, mpi, mpich

Working on Master worker using MPI . worker can be of two type . I have to split `MPI_COMM_WORLD` communicator between the different workers . But I believe the `Mpi_Comm_Split()` is a collective call and all the processes have to participate . My problem is that the workers can't split until they know what type of workers they are and the master cannot call `MPI_Comm_Split()` at that point.

Can someone suggest how to split the communicator if one of the process can't hit the `MPI_Comm_Split()` at the same time as others ?

Comment: The first parameter of [`MPI_Comm_split()`](http://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.1/www3/MPI_Comm_split.html) is the original global communicator. It can be any communicator, `MPI_COMM_WORLD` or any other. Have you tried to call `MPI_Comm_split()` twice ? Once to separate master and workers and once to build the two kind of workers.

Comment: I think this should work. But one thing i didn't realized my code uses black box code for dynamic spawning of the workers . and at any point not all the workers are active . Even in start of the code this cant be done , because that black box code decides which rank is going to be Master and once it starts master all the worker are sleeping until invoked . I believe MPI_Comm_Split() can't be used in this scene